# Xamarin.forms IconTabbedPage control more menu icons not working

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.forms

I have implemented the IconTabbedPage and it icons show for the first 4 tabs but all the tabs in the more menu don't seem to be displaying the icon. I am using the font awesome iconize plugin to display icons. They work everywhere else except for the more menu items. Not sure how to debug this to see why they are not showing. Has anyone else has this problem with the More Menu?

Also when on a iPad the tab text are running over each other and it gets all jumbled up. Has anyone experienced these issues.

I am using the Iconize plugin
https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Iconize

Comment: I tested it in my side and found the same issue, I think it may be a bug. And I'm trying to find out the source code to modify something.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT were you able to figure out why the icons are not showing in the tab view